# Unique character count function does not take into consideration all lines (C)

Tags: arrays, c, string

My goal is to write a function, that calculates the number of all the unique characters from a redirected text file (meaning until EOF is reached). The code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define ASCII_VALS 128

int strLen (char inp[])
{   
    int len = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; inp[i] != '\0'; i++){
        len++;
    
    }
    return len;

}
int countUniqueChars (char inp[])
{
    int everyCharValArr[ASCII_VALS] = {0};
    int i, j = 0;
    
    for(i = 0; i < strLen(inp); i++){
        int convToInt = inp[i] - '0';
        everyCharValArr[convToInt] = 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < ASCII_VALS; i++) {
        j += everyCharValArr[i];
    }

    return j;


}
```

**works** for one string entered via `scanf()` like so:

```
int main ()
{
    char inp[100];
    printf("Enter a string: \n");
    scanf("%99s", inp);
    printf("%d\n", countUniqueChars(inp));
    
    return 0;


}
```

But after I **change** the main function to read a redirected text file, like so:

```
int main ()
{
    char inp[100];
    int total = 0;
    
    while(fgets(inp, 100, stdin)){
        total += countUniqueChars(inp);
    
    }
    printf("%d\n", total);
    
    return 0;


}
```

and runinng the program (`./binary <input.txt`) on a **input.txt** file with contents below:

```
Toydolls
Flies
trees
rocks
things
```

the value becomes **26**, which is correct (1. word = **6** unique chars, 2. word = **5** unique chars, 3. word = **4** unique chars, 4. word = **5**, 5. word = **6** unique chars), but it obviously does not take into consideration chars that **appear on more lines**, which should not be counted as unique chars at all. My question is **How do I fix the function to accomplish this?**

Comment: `everyCharValArr[convToInt]` is a problem when `convToInt` is outside the range [0...128).

Comment: "that calculates the number of all the unique characters from stdin." --> is that calculation only 1 _line_ of input or until `stdin` returns `EOF`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It is meant for until stdin returns EOF, sorry for not stating that earlier. Already edited the question.

Comment: The first word has 6 unique characters actually which will make the sum `26` so the output you get is correct.

Comment: @AlaaMahran Thank you for pointing that out, and sorry for overlooking it. Edited the question.

Comment: Ditch `- '0'`, you are not converting ASCII *digits* to numbers. (That's not the problem you are trying to solve, but a problem nevertheless).

Comment: Your array `int everyCharValArr[ASCII_VALS] = {0};` exists *per input line* and gets reset with each new line. You need to make it persist between the lines. There are several ways to do that, I'll let you try and figure one out.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thanks for the hint! :) Hopefully, I'll figure it out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that: Note that I've added a mechanism not to count a duplicate uppercase letter and its lower case letter as unique.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define ASCII_VALS 128

int everyCharValArr[ASCII_VALS] = {0};

int strLen (char inp[])
{
    int len = 0;

    for(int i = 0; inp[i] != '\0'; i++){
        len++;
    }
    return len;

}
void FindUniqueChars (char inp[])
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < strLen(inp); i++){
        if (inp[i] > ' ' && inp[i] != (char)127)
        {
            if (inp[i] >= 'A' && inp[i] <='Z')
            {
                inp[i] = tolower(inp[i]);
            }
            everyCharValArr[(int)inp[i]] = 1;
        }
    }
}
int CountUniqueChars( void )
{
    int i, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < ASCII_VALS; i++) {
        j += everyCharValArr[i];
    }

    return j;
}

int main ()
{
    char inp[100];

    while(fgets(inp, 100, stdin)){
        FindUniqueChars(inp);
    }
    printf("%d\n", CountUniqueChars());

    return 0;
}
```